# JavaEE / JAX-RS Use JWT authentication (com.auth0)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jwt

I'm pretty new in JavaEE and need to create a Rest API with JAX-RS.
I used google to get in touch with Java Rest API's and found some articles about JWT.
I never used JWT and I'm abit confused. Right now I just know Servlet authentication and most of the articles pointed to Spring-Security.

I got few questions..

- Do I need to use Spring-Security or can I keep using my Servlet authentication?
- Is there a good example / tutorial I can use to create a JWT authentication?
- Is there something better / more secure than JWT?

Comment: I can see two directions for learning: 1) how to handle Auth0 tokens (when it is generated, how it is sent to the backend, how the backend decodes it) 2) how JAX-RS handles authentication based security. You'll see that Spring Security is optional.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to start coding something and then ask concrete questions. 
But let me cover your bullet points:

1) and 2) You can use `Spring Security` and `JWT` http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt but you do not have to. You can, for example, implement some kind of filter/interceptor to check for the `Authorization` header - the `JWT`, then check it's validity, expiration etc. It is going to work. But why would you reinvent a wheel? To know more about `JWT` I recommend reading https://jwt.io/introduction/.

3) You can't say if *there's something better than JWT*. There are many other auth mechanisms(OAuth, 2, sessions, basic auth etc), all have theirs pros and cons. And all of them can be better and worse than `JWT`, it depends on a specific case. `JWT` is obviously secure if used properly. The biggest con is, **you can NOT invalidate the token**. So if it's compromised, there's a problem.